# call a function for event.keycode with onblur event

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use `onblur` event with `event.keycode`? Is there any way to call the validate function with `onblur` event? I know it can be call with `onkeyup/down/press` but I need the `onblur` event functionality.

Can you suggest a solution to my problem?

Here is my code snippet:

```
function validate() { 
    var keycode = event.keyCode; 
    alert(+keycode); 
    if ((keycode>=48 && keycode<=57) || (keycode==37)) return true; 
    return alert("Please refine search criteria with 0-9%"); 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" nam ="name" id="name" onblur="return validate()" />
```

Comment: here is my code snippet 
function validate(){
var keycode = event.keyCode;
alert(+keycode);
if ((keycode>=48 && keycode<=57) || (keycode==37))
return true;
return alert("Please refine search criteria with 0-9%");
}

<HTML Code
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" onblur= "return validate()" />

Comment: As you can see, code inside comments is difficult to read. You can always [edit] your question to add more information. Filype already did is for you in this case.

Comment: You expected to get lastly pressed key code at onblur event?

Comment: Don't use *event.keyCode*, look at the actual content of the control. Then you don't care what the keyCode is.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind and event handler after your function:

```
var inputname = document.getElementById('name');
inputname.onblur = function(e){
    validate(e);
}
```

But `e.keyCode` will be empty because you are not firing a key event. It will returns always `0`. You should change the logic of your function. Try with keyup event. Currently your code has no sense (or just I can't find it).

Check this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Br43j/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to not use keyCode, since users can blur a control without using any keys, so the associated event won't be a keyboard event and so won't have a keyCode property. Instead, look at the value of the control. It seems it should end in a digit (0-9). The control should look like:

```
<input name="input1" onblur="return validate(this)">
```

as there is no need for a name and ID, and giving a form control with a name of "name" will mask the form's own *name* property (if it's in a form). The function can be:

```
function validate(control) {
  return /\d$/.test(control.value);
}
```

which will return true if the value ends in a digit, otherwise it returns false.